# getting mac address of connected users from a standalone AP

Tags: wireless-networking

i have this, thin/dumb standalone AP Ruckus that i use as a test equipment.

Part of my testing is to get the **MAC address** of currently connected wireless users via API or any possible methods, and use the gathered data for some scripts.

any suggestions on how to get the MAC address?

Answer (score 0):

The only piece of equipment that will have all the MAC address is the router (unless another machine has connected to to the all first) so you will need to scrape the admin interface of your router.

Mimicking the admin user connecting to the web interface and viewing the routing table(or what ever it is called on your router).

Look at curl and wget, both can save cookies from a successful login event and replay them to view an authorised page.